# Rename multiple files currently in %Y%m%d%H%M%S to unix epoch time in Python

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

I need to convert hundreds of file names from %Y%m%d%H%M%S such as '20170125211201' to unix epoch time. I was able to do so to individual files with

```
>>> import os
>>> f='20170125211201'
>>> import time 
>>> date_time='20170125204151'
>>> pattern='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
>>> epoch=int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time,pattern)))
>>> new_name='{}'.format(epoch)
>>> os.rename(f,new_name)
```

I still need to do the same thing to hundreds of other files with the same file pattern but have had no luck. 
I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: try match and extract time like filename with regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your task using this snippet of code:

```
import datetime
import glob
import os
import shutil

input_dir = '/home/username/input_dir' # here should be path to directory with input files
output_dir = '/home/username/output_dir' # here should be path to output directory for new files
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dir, '*'))

for filename in files:
    basename = os.path.basename(filename)
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(basename)
    try:
        epoch = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(basename, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').timestamp())
    except:
        print('Unexpected format of filename: {}'.format(filename))
    out_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, ''.join([str(epoch), extension]))
    shutil.copy(filename, out_filename)
```